# ¿como colocar un echo en un div?

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo este codigo html de un login:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" style="border-radius: 20px;" type="text" placeholder="name@example.com" name="usuario" />
                                            <label for="inputEmail">Usuario</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password" style="border-radius: 20px;" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
                                            <label for="inputPassword">Contraseña</label>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-4 mb-0">
                                    
                                    
                                            
                                            <button style="border-radius: 10px; margin-left:170px" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Ingresar</button>
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

me gustaria colocar este echo adentro de este login, para que salga como alerta en algun lugar y se vea mas bonito; tengo este codigo php:

```
 <?php    
if ($num >0) {
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    $password_bd = $row ['password'];
    $pass_c = sha1($password);


     if ($password_bd ==$pass_c) {
      
        $_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['nombre']= $row['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['tipo_usuario']= $row['tipo_usuario'];

        header("location: principal.php");
     }

     else{
        echo "<div class='alerta1'>contraseña incorrecta</div>";
        
     }
}
else{
    echo "<script>alert('El usuario no existe');</script>";

}
}

?>`
```

en el momento los tengo con el siguien estilo, simplemente centrados y con color rojo

```
    <style type="text/css">
.alerta1{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

### agradezco la ayuda chicos.
Quiero que ese echo en letras rojas salga adentro del contenedor del login, gracias

Comment: Ahh pero tu quieres comprobar el envio de un formulario entonces.

Comment: Podrías hacerlo creando una sesion con el valor que quieres mostrar, después ya solo muestras el valor de la sesion, y como en este caso es un div entonces te crearía el div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo llevas hasta ahora, vas bien. Solo falta obtener y comprobar el envio de formulario.

Usaré y comentaré tu código para que veas como se obtienen los datos post enviar el formulario.

Para ello usaremos, dentro de la misma página el `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"`

Acá, si el usuario no es "Usuario", mandará la alerta.
Si la password no es "1234", mandará el echo del div color rojo.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_POST["usuario"] === "Usuario") {
        if ($_POST["password"] === "1234") {
            /*
        $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        $password_bd = $row['password'];
        $pass_c = sha1($password);
        if ($password_bd == $pass_c) {*/
            /*
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
            $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['tipo_usuario'];
            header("location: principal.php");
            */
        } else {
            echo "<div class='alerta1'>contraseña incorrecta</div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('El usuario no existe');</script>";
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .alerta1 {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" style="border-radius: 20px;" type="text" placeholder="name@example.com" name="usuario" />
            <label for="inputEmail">Usuario</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password" style="border-radius: 20px;" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
            <label for="inputPassword">Contraseña</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-4 mb-0">
            <button style="border-radius: 10px; margin-left:170px" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Ingresar</button>
            <br>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias bro , funcionó genial

Comment: Recuerda darme un voto si te ayude ;)

Comment: JAJAJA bro, mantienes en esto 24/7 o q? JJAJAJJA

Comment: Nop XD solo es casualidad